# Fedora missing in Grub after installation

Tags: linux, fedora, dual-boot, system-installation, grub

I have installed Fedora 36 for the first time (UEFI), but Grub only shows the option to boot Windows boot manager, and Fedora doesn't appear.

I haven't tried to change anything yet because I don't know what's wrong. I have probably set all my partitions right and did everything else right. Also, I can't boot any other Linux distribution because I only have Windows and Fedora, which I installed recently.